# Website showing random code like texts in a post after pasting from MS Word

Tags: content

My website is showing this type of content in a blog. When I click the title of same content, the content is fine there. It shows this type of content in one of the many listed contents. What can be the possible reason?

```
Normal
0

false
false
false

EN-AU
X-NONE
X-NONE



DefSemiHidden="false" DefQFormat="false" DefPriority="99"
LatentStyleCount="371">


UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 2"/>
UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 3"/>
UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 4"/>
UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 5"/>
UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 6"/>
UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 7"/>
UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 8"/>
UnhideWhenUsed=”true” QFormat=”true” Name=”heading…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that your problem is that you have pasted from MS Word.  Go into your post and select "text" instead of "visual".  Remove the markup.  Alternatively, paste the article into Notepad, and then copy and paste back out of it into the visual editor.